# Change given date format in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, date

I'm having date "`1/19/12 00:00:00`" (M/D/Y) .I want to change this date as "`2012-01-19 00:00:00`"(Y-M-D).

How can i do this.

I'm using jQuery ui date picker.Date picker formate is **dateFormat:"m/d/y"** I want to convert this date in on select.

```
onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
//here i want to convert
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
   onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
       var d = new Date(inst.selectedYear,inst.selectedMonth,inst.selectedDay);
       var mydate = $.datepicker.formatDate( 'yy/mm/dd', d);
       alert(mydate);
   }
});
```

a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YbzAT/) for this

[Documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate) for formatDate

Answer (score 0):

```
      Date.format = 'yyyy-mm-dd';
    $(function()
    {
      $('.date-pick').datePicker()
     });
```

Try this

```
   $valz123=YOUR INPUT DATE

   var d =parseDate($valz123);

  $valz123=d.format("yyyy-mm-dd");


    function parseDate(input) 
{

var parts = input.match(/(\d+)/g);
return new Date(parts[0], parts[1]-1, parts[2]);

}
```

Comment: i don't want to change the datepicker date format just want to change selectedDate

Answer (score 0):

The dateFormat to be used for the altField option. This allows one date format to be shown to the user for selection purposes, while a different format is actually sent behind the scenes. For a full list of the possible formats see the formatDate function

Code examples

Initialize a datepicker with the altFormat option specified.

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
```

Get or set the altFormat option, after init.

```
//getter
var altFormat = $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "altFormat" );
//setter
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "altFormat", 'yy-mm-dd' );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to reformat the string:

```
var d = '1/19/12 00:00:00';

function convert(d) {
  var b = d.split(/[\/ ]/g);
  return '20' + b[2] + '-' + z(b[0]) + '-' + z(b[1]) + ' ' + b[3];

  function z(n) {
    n = Number(n);
    return (n<10? '0' : '') + n;
  }
}

alert( convert(d) ); // 2012-01-19 00:00:00
```